# how to add css files in index.html using web pack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I am new to webpack & want to add all the css files bundled and added to to the index.html file in dist.

my webpack.config.js file

```js
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports  = function(env) {

    return {
  entry: {main:'./app/index.js',
  vendor: 'moment'
},
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
   module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
             include: helpers.root('app'),
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "css-loader",
               use: 'style-loader'
           })
        },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
        ]},
  plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ['vendor', , 'manifest'] 
            }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),

         new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'app/index.html',
            inject: 'body'
            })
        ]
  }
};
```

However it does not create styles.css file. 
Thanks in advance.